# Compare rows in db and select if value is greater than 15%

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select rows that have changes greater than 15% when the dates are the same.
Here's an example of the db data that I want to compare.

```
id      coin        high24hr    low24hr     date
397     BTC_1CR     0.00030000  0.00030000  2016-06-10 08:39:26
525     BTC_LSK     0.00078898  0.00078898  2016-06-10 08:39:26
529     BTC_1CR     0.00030000  0.00030000  2016-06-10 08:48:05
657     BTC_LSK     0.00078884  0.00078884  2016-06-10 08:48:05
```

So I want to select any rows that have those the two times 2016-06-10 08:39:26 and 2016-06-10 08:48:05. Then if the 2 coin column values are the same. Compare the high24hr column values. If the difference is greater than 15% higher return the difference. if it's not return 0. And then compare low24hr column values. If the difference is greater than 15% lower return the difference. if it's not return 0.

And the output should be something like the following. Showing the percentage change if it's greater than 15%.

```
coin        high    low
BTC_1CR     20%     25%
BTC_LSK     30%     0
```

Comment: Can you add the desired output for the given sample please?

Comment: Are you only using sql? Or are you pairing it with another language? Like php or similar?

Comment: I'll be using php with this. I'm sure I could just go through the results in php and do my logic there. but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL uses set operations so you usually don't think of comparing 2 sequential rows; however, you could do with this query something similar:

```
declare @percent  float
set @percent = 0.0000000000000000015;

select distinct t.coin,t.date,
    (t1.high24hr-t.high24hr)/100.0 as high, 
    (t2.low24hr-t.low24hr)/100.0 as low 
    from YourTable t
    left join YourTable t1 on 
        t.coin=t1.coin and t.date>t1.date and (t1.high24hr-t.high24hr)/100.0>@percent
    left join YourTable t2 on 
        t.coin=t2.coin and t.date>t2.date and (t2.low24hr-t.low24hr)/100.0>@percent
```